# Why does graphql-ruby function definition work via kwarg, but not via the function method in a block?

Tags: graphql, graphql-ruby

Where

```
class FindRecord < GraphQL::Function
  ...
  argument :id, !types.ID
  ...
end
```

this variation of a field definition within a `GraphQL::ObjectType.define` block works without error:

```
 field 'd1', DirectoryType, function: FindRecord.new(:directory)
```

But for the same query this fails with the error message *"Field 'd2' doesn't accept argument 'id'"*:

```
field 'd2', DirectoryType do                                                                                
  function FindRecord.new(:directory)                                                               
end
```

After those fields are defined, for both `d1` and `d2` the value of `target.fields['d?'].function` is the same (with different object ids). But it looks like in the block version the function doesn't get applied to the field.

It also doesn't work when I skip the `field` helper and define the field like this:

```
target.fields[name] = GraphQL::Field.define {
  ...
  function FindRecord.new(:directory)
  ...
}
```

Am I calling the function method wrong? Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use resolve in the block instead of function (which is an option to the field method, and not a helper available on the block):

```
field 'd2', DirectoryType do                                                                                
  resolve FindRecord.new(:directory)                                                               
end
```

because Functions usually implement the same `call(obj, args, ctx)` method, then they can be considered `Callables` and you should be able to use it with the resolve helper instead of the usual way:

```
field :students, types[StudentType] do
  argument :grade, types.Int
  resolve ->(obj, args, ctx) {
    Student.where(grade: args[:grade])
  }
end
```

Comment: But then the arguments in the function don't get applied and have to be added separately to each field.

Comment: Well, they should be added because `FindRecord.new(:directory).call` as receives the same arguments. If they are not getting applied then you might try: `resolve ->(obj, args,ctx) { FindRecord.new(:directory).call(obj, args,ctx) }`

Comment: This didn't solve the problem, but it was the only attempt and a reasonable one, so awarding the bounty. Thank you @elyalvarado.